# How do I choose between salary, skills and future?

Tags: career-development, careers, career-switch, skills, websites

I'm working in a very small startup as a web developer  since last 8 months, . I’ve learned web skills quite well. Now they are switching their backend to another technology, which I don’t know.

I don’t have any problem in learning the new technology and continuing things, but at the same time I'm concerned about salary too. My current salary is just the amount needed for my monthly living. But I need some more money than that so that I don't have to think twice while buying clothes or eating well.

My plan is to switch company after 4 months as I would be having 1 year's experience. But than, I won't be able to state to interviewer that I've worked for 1 year in a particular field. They would not consider my 1 year experience as really 1 year. I feel a little worry about that. Also,  I don't want to be a 'trainee' once again. But again, the good thing in learning the new technology, is that I can learn new skill in a wide spread technology.

So, I'm really confused. Moreover, I'm 25 years old. Most of my batch mates are already earning more than me, because somehow money was their first choice.

Would it be wise to learn new skills till one more year and switch later? Or should I change it right now and have a better salary?  How can I make this choice?

Answer (score 2):

in 15 years you will look back at this and want to tell yourself never chase the money.   [Dave Ramsey's advice](https://www.daveramsey.com/blog/debt-free-and-loving-it) is it is fine to sacrifice in the short run for a better future over the long haul. His advice linked is about getting out of debt, but the same principles apply to building your career.  And he has a history of helping turn peoples lives around.

If you can afford to invest in yourself by building your skills now take the time now to get into something you will enjoy and you can be successful at.  The money will come in time and you will be happier.  Don't be afraid of a trainee tag now.  You are only 25.  You have 40 more years of productive life that trainee tag is only there for a short time.  Better to take it now than when you are 40 and realize you hate what you are doing.

Comment: I **absolutely** agree with DaveRamsey's advice about getting out of debt (so, don't get in to debt and if you do foolishly have debt, pay it off fast).  But that has no connection to building a career (ie, "being paid a lot").  Ramsey would **urge** the OP to do what it takes in their career to make more money.

Comment: @Fattie - You will never hear Dave suggest that money is more important than happiness.  Maybe in the short term but never over more than a sprint to pay off debt.  Ill eat this computer if you can show me otherwise.

Comment: @Fattie, No, the one only reason to work is...whatever you want it to be. Some people are motivated by money. Some want to do something they find meaningful. Some just want to pay the bills while they pursue other interests. Everyone has a different motivation for doing what they do. Only you can decide what you want, and only Vikas can decide what they want.

Answer (score -5):

> "How do I choose between salary, skills and future?"

Always choose salary.

Your future is - your salary.

Your skills will only be developed by - more and more challenging jobs, which are indeed the jobs with higher salaries.

In 15 years your programming career will be over, you'll be too old. (With luck you'll then be able to move to more technical-high-level and/or management roles.)

You'll need to look back and ensure you chose the most skills-growing jobs (which are those with the higher salary at every step),

and that in 2040 you have a high income (which is only possible if you extremely aggressively increase your income every year, every month, with no gaps, and no letup).

Comment: 22 years ago I started my career with a job doing tech support. 8 years later i was managing a decent sized IT department and realized I did not want to do that for the rest of my life.  I stepped down, changed paths took a huge pay cut and started over.  I was just a bit older than the OP.  I make more than double now than I was making, and at least 50% more than I would have made had i stayed miserable and moved slowly up the management ladder.  So maybe not always

Comment: (In my experience, when someone DOES leave a career for a different one, in the longer run it always works out better, don't you reckon?)

Comment: Not at all I left a job making 80k a year and went to 13/hour...  but i was alot happier.  Which translated to doing a better job which translated to growth and advancement.